# Visual Studio Code don't load account on some projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

for several days now, Visual Studio code does not load me extensions and user account in some projects. If I rename the project folder then I do load it. Any idea what may be going on?

Comment: Is it the project folder name that is the problem? Or do you think the change is what fixes it. Meaning, if you changed it back to the original name does VS Code stop working properly again.

Comment: Is the project folder sincronizing to any cloud drive? OneDrive for example. I houst to get the same problems and removing the sincronization to cloud solved them.

Comment: @JohnB , Yes, if I change back to the original name, VSCode malfunctions.

Comment: @MERLIN, the folder is not synced with any cloud drive, only github.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the \Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage folder works correctly